# The absolute uri: http://www.springframework.org/tags cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, gradle, spring-boot

I know that this question had been asked before. But none of the previous answers apply to my case. I am using gradle and spring boot. When I use

**gradlew bootRun**

everything is OK. But when I use

**gradlew clean build && java -jar build\libs\myjar.jar**

I get the following error when I open my jsp files

**The absolute uri: http://www.springframework.org/tags cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application**

What is the difference between bootRun and clean build && java -jar? If there is a problem in my build.gradle then how come bootRun runs successfully? Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: the classloader is different. There are some [limitations to using JSP](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jsp-limitations) with Spring Boot embedded applications. especially taglibs. In particular it never works with Jetty. Tomcat should be OK if you stick to a WAR format. If I were you I'd stay away from JSP, as there are so many better ways to write a view layer now.

Comment: Thanks. That seems to answer my question. Will try the WAR solution first. If it still doesn't work, will try another view layer

Comment: Which of those better ways to write a view layer might you recommend?

Comment: I think that's quite a personal decision (so not really on topic). I often use Freemarker. Also like Mustache. Also supported out of the box in Spring Boot are Thymeleaf, Groovy and Velocity.